# Difference and connection between generative learning, discriminative learning and max-margin learning

Tags: machine-learning, svm, discriminant-analysis, generative-models

I once heard that, generative learning, discriminative learning and max-margin learning can be separated in terms of their respective definition of loss function. I am not sure how to achieve that?